# How is Electrum able to find my default wallet even though I deleted it?

Tags: wallet, electrum, wallet-security

OK I didn't delete it. I closed Electrum, renamed the wallet to `xxx.default_wallet.xxx` and moved it to my Desktop from `C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Roaming\Electrum\wallets`. I wanted to test wallet restore. However, it opened the default wallet still! How is it able to find the default wallet file when the file it's looking for doesn't exist? Does it store the wallet in the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I had another instance open to another wallet. It must have kept all the wallets in memory. When I closed the last instance, it wrote another `default_wallet` to disk.